# How can I add a line marker onto a D3.js bar chart?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, data-analysis

I am new to D3.js (version 5) but I have been able to create basic bar chart using JSON data. The Y axis labels grade percentage, and the X axis labels dates. At the moment it displays the grades per month. **How can add a line marker that labels the targeted grade for each month? Additionally, how can I add the horizontal lines that move across the chart from each Y axis tick and a legend?**

**My bar chart:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ4uq.png)

**Desired bar chart:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9gJ7.png)

**Code**:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Grade %</h1>
    <div id="GradeChart"></div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    // Data Example
    data = { 
    'month': date, 'grade': 90, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 89, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 78, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 99, 'target': 100,
    'month': date, 'grade': 50, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 60, 'target': 90,
    'month': date, 'grade': 65, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 75, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 86, 'target': 80,
    'month': date, 'grade': 100, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 1, 'target': 85,
    'month': date, 'grade': 27, 'target': 85,
    };

    const width = 1200;
    const height = 600;
    const margin = { top: 50, bottom: 150, left: 50, right: 50 };

    const svg = d3.select('#GradeChart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr('height', height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
        .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

    const x = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(d3.range(data.length))
        .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
        .padding(0.1)

    const y= d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

    svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("fill", 'royalblue')
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .join("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => x(i))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.percent))
        .attr('title', (d) => d.percent)
        .attr("class", "rect")
        .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.percent))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

    function yAxis(g) {
        g.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, 0)`)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, data.format))
        .attr("font-size", '20px')
    }

    function xAxis(g) {
        g.attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(i => data[i].month))
        .attr("font-size", '20px')
        .selectAll("text")  
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)")
    }

    svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
    svg.append("g").call(yAxis);
    svg.node();
</script>
```

I tried to append target data as another bar to create a grouped bar chart, but the bars overlapped instead of being side by side. The bar underneath would not be visible if its value was less than the one on top.

```
    svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("fill", 'green')
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .join("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => x(i))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.target))
        .attr('title', (d) => d.target)
        .attr("class", "rect")
        .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.target))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of d3.js not as a library to draw charts, but rather a toolbox to visualize data in SVG and HTML (hence the name *Data-Driven Documents*).
This is more abstract and tedious. But it gives you full control over how you want to visualize your data.

**Lines On Bar Chart**

You can draw the graph for the target grades by adding another group of `line` elements to your svg.

```
svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'target-grades')
    .attr('stroke', 'green')
    .attr('stroke-width', 5)
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(data)
    .join('line')
    .attr('x1', (dataItemForMonth, index) => {
      // catch the very beginning of the array
      if (index > 0) {
        // get the x coordinate fo the previous sample
        return x(index - 1) + x.bandwidth() / 2;
      } else {
        return x(index) + x.bandwidth() / 2; // create a zero line (same start and end point)
      }
    })
    .attr('y1', (dataItemForMonth, index) => {
      // catch the very beginning of the array
      if (index > 0) {
        // get the data item of the previous month
        let fromLineDataPoint = data[index - 1];
        // use the same scale for vertical positioning
        return y(fromLineDataPoint.target);
      } else {
        return y(dataItemForMonth.target); // zero line
      }
    })
    .attr('x2', (dataItemForMonth, index) => {
      // same as for the bar charts
      return x(index) + x.bandwidth() / 2;
    })
    .attr('y2', (dataItemForMonth) => {
      // use the same scale for vertical positioning
      return y(dataItemForMonth.target);
    });
```

For each month in the `data` array, this code draws a green line from the previous month (start of the line - `x1`/`y1`) to the current month (end of the line - `x2`/`y2`).
Note that we account for the first month which does not have a previous month. In this case, the code creates a line with the same start and end point.

**The Y Axis Horizontal Lines**

Use `tickSize()` to create tick lines which cover the full width of your chart.

```
d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(null, data.format)
    // the minus points the ticks to the right - full width minus margins
    .tickSize(-(width - margin.left - margin.right))
```

In order to draw the chart content (bars and target grades) above the tick lines, add the y-axis to a group created before all other content.

```
const svg = d3.select('#GradeChart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width - margin.left - margin.right)
    .attr('height', height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

var groupForYAxis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y-axis');

// all content. rects and lines
// ...

groupForYAxis.call(yAxis);
```

**Legend**

As mentioned above, you have to construct the visualization of the legend yourself.
There is no magic d3 `legend` function.

```
var legendGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  // where ever you want to place your legend
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 10)');

// the rect
legendGroup.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', 50)
  .attr('height', 25)
  .attr('fill', 'royalblue');
legendGroup.append('text')
  .attr('x', 55)
  .attr('y', 18)
  .text('Grades');

// the targets
legendGroup.append('line')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('y1', 45)
  .attr('x2', 50)
  .attr('y2', 45)
  .attr('stroke', 'green')
  .attr('stroke-width', 5);
legendGroup.append('text')
  .attr('x', 55)
  .attr('y', 50)
  .text('Targets');
```

All of this produces the following:
[image: Bar charts with graph overlay]